# CSS - Div padding "all except z pixels"

Tags: css, html, centering

I have a div that needs to stretch the whole way across the page, but the actual content should only be z pixels wide, and centered. That is, the text is not centered, but the area where the content is - the interior of the div, if you will - is centered.

The logical approach is to do something like this:

```
<div>
<!--I stretch across the entire page!-->
 <div>
 <!--I am z pixels wide, and my margins are auto. Content goes here.-->
 </div>
</div>
```

The only problem with this is that it seems really div-itis-y. This is something that should be able to be achieved using the box model.

Is there anyway to do this without adding divs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`body` already stretches the width of the page, so just use that one interior `div`

something like

```
<body>
    <div></div>
</body>
```

and

```
div{
    width:980px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

This is what `div`s are meant to do.

Now, depending on the content and whether or not you are using HTML5, you may want to wrap it all in another element tag, such as `header`, `nav`, `section` etc.

But there is nothing inherently wrong with using `div`s, even nested ones.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I need the external div to be a swath of color that spans the page.

Comment: I also agree - there is nothing inherently wrong with using divs - it's just easier to maintain a page with fewer, more logical divs.

Comment: That's true @guywhoneedsahand